# OpenCV putText() is too slow for multiple lines. How to speed it up?

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11

I need to overlay about ~50 lines of text on a video stream from an IP camera. But I have found that I cannot use the newline character in `putText()`, I have to split and print each line individually, which means multiple calls to `putText()`. This method slows down the video stream from 30 fps to ~3 fps and overloads the video encoder in my IP camera. Are there any methods to improve performance when calling `putText` multiple times?
My code is similar to the following:

```
void* TextThread(){
    std::vector<std::string> infoValues{...};
    int verticalShift = 0;
    for (auto it = infoValues.begin(); it != infoValues.end(); ++it, verticalShift++){
        cv::putText(img, *it, cv::Point(1470, 30 + 25*verticalShift), FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.85, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0), 2, LINE_AA);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you cache the text words' or characters' own image and blend them with the result frame of video? I think whole alphabet could fit in L2 cache and have hundred(s) gigabytes per second throughput.

Comment: change LINE_AA to something simpler. that antialiasing costs time. -- see if you can render the text using anything other than OpenCV. -- I too wish OpenCV came with bitmap fonts. those are cheap to draw. OpenCV only comes with one small set of vector fonts and the drawing code is _not_ as optimized as all the drawing code for regular vector fonts in most systems.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz you made good points. wish OpenCV takes suggestions from the developers.

Comment: oh they (paid developers) do, but there's been a mountain of work ahead of them for a long while. OpenCV 5.0 will come with freetype by default (was implemented in 2020/2021) and that should fix almost everyone's gripes, but nobody knows when this `next` branch will be ready for release. most suggestions just sit in the github issues until some volunteer finds it and works on it. Google Summer of Code can take care of some groups of issues.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz is there any other way to draw text over frame faster than puttex?

Comment: depends, is the text different every time, or the same?